# Multithreading doesn't work. What is incorrect?

Tags: java, multithreading

It's a little program written with a purpose of studying multithreading. I expected to get in main method different random numbers after run. About 4 numbers per second. But I got many thousands of zeros. Where is an error?

Main Class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExternalWorld externalWorld = new ExternalWorld();
        externalWorld.start();

        int x = 0;
        while (true) {
            while(!externalWorld.signal){
                System.out.println("qqq");}
            System.out.println(++x + ") " + externalWorld.getAnInt());
        }
    }
}
```

ExternalWorld Class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class ExternalWorld extends Thread {

    private int anInt = 0;
    public boolean signal = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random(100);
        while(true) {
            anInt = random.nextInt(100);
            signal = true;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                signal = false;
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public int getAnInt() {
        if (!signal) {
            int p = 1 / 0;
        }
        int result = anInt;
        anInt = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is happening?  Have you tried to debug `run`?

Comment: Multithreading *does* work. Make sure to write a *relevant* title, which should be an accurate and useful summary of the question/problem.

Comment: why would you do this `if (!signal) {
            int p = 1 / 0;
        }` ? divideByZero error ?

Comment: I suggest you use a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: I expected to get for 200 ms (when signal == true) anInt and for 50 ms (when signal == false) string "qqq". But I got many zeros. I trued to debug run and main, but I saw only run breakpoints and no breakpoints from main.

Comment: DivideByZero is used for getting error when signal == false, but line System.out.println(++x + ") " + externalWorld.getAnInt()); executes.

Comment: I added volatile to fields in ExternalWorld class and line signal = false; in getAnInt() method. And it works! Thank you all

Comment: @Anton always click the check mark on the answer below to mark this question as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**problem:**

```
private int anInt = 0;
public boolean signal = false;
```

You are access those variables from one thread to another thus giving you `0` and `false` on the main thread

**solution:**

use `volatile` keyword to access those variables from multiple threads

**sample:**

```
private volatile int anInt = 0;
public volatile boolean signal = false;
```